# Can default Google Map click and hover behaviors be preserved when used in Leaflet?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, google-places-api

On a plain Google Map, the user can interact with the points of interest (POIs) that are displayed. Specifically, on hover they will see a pointer that indicates clickability, and on click they get a popup with information about the POI. Clicks will also generate an event from the Google Map that contains a placeId, which can be used to retrieve further information from about the POI.

When using Google Mutant with Leaflet, those default behaviors are not present. This is demonstrated with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57L7L6ox/4/), the code of which I'll include below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #googleMap, #leafletMap {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    </style>

    <title>Leaflet with Google Maps</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
        var lat = 38.917855;
        var lng = -77.2210604;
        var zoom = 18;

        var leafletMap = new L.Map('leafletMap', {center: new L.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: zoom});
        var roads = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
            type: 'roadmap'
        }).addTo(leafletMap);

        var googleOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), googleOptions);

        }//]]> 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Google</h1>
    <div id="googleMap"></div>
    <h1>Leaflet</h1>
    <div id="leafletMap"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can the Leaflet map be made to exhibit the Google Map click and hover behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the Leaflet map be made to exhibit the Google Map click and hover behavior?

Yes it probably is possible, but that is *tremendous* work.

> Can default Google Map click and hover behaviors be preserved when used in Leaflet?

I would rather say that you would like to *re-implement* the interactivity behaviour, rather than "preserve" it, since it is an extra functionality.

You should realize that the "markers" and text you see on Google Maps are "hard coded" as pixels on raster tiles (open your browser network log / console and you will see requests to those tiles. The tile images will show the basemap with POI and text).

The Leaflet plugin that you have used just re-uses those images.

With only those tiles in hand, it is impossible to tell what is a POI (since it is just pixels among others from the basemap), hence to implement any interactivity.

On the other hand, Google Maps fetches *in parallel* metadata for the area in the viewport, which gives those POI's position, text and interactive area. In your network log you will see requests to TXT files containing that data.

Therefore it *might* be possible to hook into Google Maps library to retrieve that metadata as well and use it in Leaflet, but you would have to implement this hook and duplicate the interactivity yourself.